# Cant run rails commands. Your Ruby version is 2.2.1, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, terminal, version

I am not able to run surver `rails s` or cant make controllers etc. What should I do ?

Terminal showing following error:

```
Your Ruby version is 2.2.1, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.4
```

Answer (score 16):

Run `ruby -v` then you will see that you've installed ruby 2.2.1, but the first line in your Gemfile specifies to use `ruby 2.1.4`. Change the first line in your Gemfile to specify `ruby 2.2.1` or install `ruby 2.1.4`
If you want to use previous version ruby 2.1.4. Then first check if it is already installed or not by using `rvm list` command. If it is there then you need to run `rvm use ruby-2.1.4` command and if it is not there use

```
rvm install ruby-2.1.4

rvm use ruby-2.1.4
```

Comment: how do I install ruby previous version?

Answer (score 0):

It might be using your system ruby version

In your apache config use:

To find your path use `passenger-config about ruby-command`

`PassengerRuby /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/bin/ruby`

Source: [phusion passenger docs](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/deploy/apache/deploy/ruby/)